# MySQL Join query is returning too many results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT huxwz_user_orders.*, huxwz_users.name, huxwz_users.email, SUM(huxwz_user_orderitems.price) 
FROM huxwz_user_orders 
LEFT OUTER JOIN huxwz_users 
    ON (huxwz_user_orders.userid = huxwz_users.id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN huxwz_user_orderitems 
    ON (huxwz_user_orders.id = huxwz_user_orderitems.orderid) 
WHERE huxwz_user_orders.id like '%20%'
Group BY huxwz_user_orderitems.orderid
ORDER BY huxwz_user_orders.id DESC
```

The query above returns 23 results. Thing is, when I do a query like this `select * from huxwz_user_orders WHERE id LIKE '%20%' ORDER BY id DESC`, it returns 20 results.

What am I doing wrong? :/ and can someone come with a fix?

Comment: Formatting your scripts doesn't hurt. Reading a 20000 character long line does. And once, you'll have to read the script back... Finding a tiny mistake in a badly formatted code - whatever the language might be - can be a real pain.

Comment: try select count(*) from huxwz_user_orders

Comment: @DamirSudarevic what do you propose I do? ^^

Comment: Please show some sample data, and the results you're hoping to get from it.

Comment: Basically, I'm expecting it to return the same amount of data as it would if I used the second query. I want all the data from the main table (huxwz_user_orders), and the associated email and name (huxwz_users), and at last I want the sum of the prices that are in the huxwz_user_orderitems, on the same table. If that makes any sense :)

Comment: I didn't ask you to DESCRIBE what you wanted, I asked you to SHOW it. Make page at sqlfiddle.com so we can experiment.

Comment: I'm not totaly sure on the mySQL-flavour but I suppose that the group by should be on huxwz_user_orders.id to achieve what you want

Comment: That actually did the trick ! :3 Thank you kind sir

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting more than one hit per huxwz_user_orders on any of the other two tables.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
Group BY huxwz_user_orderitems.orderid
```

to

```
Group By huxwz_user_orders.id
```